# Can't grant ALTER permission on database role?

Tags: sql-server, permissions, alter, sql-grant

I have a Database Role named `ApplicationUsers`. I want to grant members of this role the `ALTER` permission for this same role, so that existing members can add or remove other members. Here is the SQL statement I've tried:

```
GRANT ALTER ON [dbo].[ApplicationUsers] TO [ApplicationUsers]
```

I get the following error:

> Cannot find the object 'ApplicationUsers', because it does not exist or you do not have permission.

I can confirm that the user account I'm executing the `GRANT` command from *does* have the required permission. If I run `fn_my_permissions(NULL, 'DATABASE')` one of the values returned is `ALTER ANY ROLE`.

I've double checked that the role exists and that it is spelled correctly. Here is a snipping from SSMS:

[image: Image from SSMS]

What am I missing?

**EDIT:**

Thanks to the answer from David, I got the command to execute succesfully, however it doesn't actually seem to work. Members of the `ApplicationUsers` group still seem to be denied permission to add other members. When looking at the role's properties in SSMS, the permissions are missing:

[image: Permissions shown in SSMS]

This is after running the following commands:

```
GRANT ALTER ON ROLE::ApplicationUsers TO ApplicationUsers WITH GRANT OPTION
```

Comment: I would suggest you are either connected to the wrong database, or the `ROLE` does not exist in the database you are connected to, if you definitely have the required permissions.

Comment: Note, if you've explicitly been denied access to alter the table, then that could also affect your permissions to allow others to access it.

Comment: @Larnu I'm definitly connected to the right database and the role definitely exists. I've edited the question to include a screenshot from SSMS to show it. I don't believe I have any `DENY` permissions set (I'm testing this as the `db_owner`).

Comment: Apologies, I had misread. I had *assumed* that `[dbo].[ApplicationUsers]` was a table/view/etc with the same name as the database role.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's unusual to allow members of a role to add and remove members or rename the role.  But you can do it like this:

```
GRANT ALTER ON role::[ApplicationUsers] TO [ApplicationUsers]
```

But it looks like that's not allowed, and the grant silently does nothing.  Instead introduce an ApplicationAdmins role and grant the ALTER on ApplictionUsers to that.  eg

```
create role ApplicationUsers
create role ApplicationAdmins
GRANT ALTER ON role::ApplicationUsers TO ApplicationAdmins

grant select to ApplicationUsers

select p.name grantee, perm.*
from sys.database_permissions perm
join sys.database_principals p
  on perm.grantee_principal_id = p.principal_id
where class_desc = 'DATABASE_PRINCIPAL'
go
alter role ApplicationUsers add member ApplicationAdmins
alter role ApplicationAdmins add member user1

go
create table ApplicationTable(id int)
go

execute as user='user1'
  alter role applicationusers add member user2
  select * from ApplicationTable
revert
```

Comment: This command completed successfully, but some seems to not have worked. I've updated my question with more information.